# Unsetting Session not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, session, wordpress, session-cookies

I am trying to unset the session so that when a user navigates to a new page it unsets the previous session and starts a new. It is kind of working however it only works on two refreshes. Obviously it works immediately with a cache refresh and I just don't know where I am going wrong. I have tried about 25 different variations such as session_destroy(), $_SESSION = array() and a load more.

**Session Created:**
I thought you should unset the session here to get rid of the previous session.

```html
session_start();
session_unset();

$exclude_popular = $wp_list_ids;
$_SESSION['popular'] = $exclude_popular;

session_write_close();
```

**GET Session:**

```html
session_start();
$exclude_popular = $_SESSION['popular'];

<!-- MY CODE THAT I NEED THE SESSION FOR. -->

session_write_close();
```

So any ideas why it works on two refreshes and not one? It doesn't make a difference if I remove session_unset either. session_unset seems to be doing nothing in this case but included it for good measure so someone might be able to spot my mistake.

All helps appreciated and I have looked through stackoverflow extensively but just can't seem to get it to work :S

**EDIT:EDIT: FIXED THIS BY STARTING SESSION AT TOP OF PAGE, now works crossbrowser. Still need help getting my seesion to reset though :. Just noticed that the session is only working in Chrome. It does not seem to be working, at all, in Firefox or IE.**